# How can I get a list of Tokens in a Solana Wallet?

Tags: node.js, api, blockchain, solana

I'm trying to get list of owned tokens from a wallet address. In the solana web3 documentation, there is a property of `Connecton` called `getTokenAccountsByOwner`, but I'm getting type error: `mintAddress.toBase58 is not a function`.

Here's the code I use:

```
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Connection, programs } = require('@metaplex/js');
const axios = require('axios');

..

console.log(solanaConnection.getTokenLargestAccounts('2MTPtFo78QzWJaK9PGk9pZm9dFrVVSBGCRWPpND25GAe'));
```

Comment: https://solanacookbook.com/ingredients/get-program-accounts.html This can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are some bits mixed around between your question and your code, since the question references `getTokenAccountsByOwner` but then the code shows `getTokenLargestAccounts`.

Either way, you're passing in a string, when you should be passing in a `PublicKey`.  You can instead try:

```
console.log(solanaConnection.getTokenLargestAccounts(new PublicKey('2MTPtFo78QzWJaK9PGk9pZm9dFrVVSBGCRWPpND25GAe')));
```

Comment: Not sure how this fixed the issue. The docs clearly say base-58 encoded string is required as the argument.
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner

Comment: For JSON RPC, yes it's expecting a string, but the web3 bindings expect a `PublicKey`, which it then converts to a base58 string.  Here's the code: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/428575f9aefd5155de6419307321c17a827c43cf/web3.js/src/connection.ts#L2403